# Using a mysqldump export to create data with a different database name

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am using the following to import database using a mysqldump export:

```
mysql -u root -p example_db < path/to/export.sql
```

I would like to import the database to a database with a different name to the one referenced in `export.sql`. Is there a way to do this other than manually editing the `export.sql` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option **--no-create-db** when you execute your **mysqldump**, this option avoid inserting **CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name;** in dump file.

Max.

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference. I discovered that using `--databases db_name` in the mysqldump resulted in the `USE db_name` in the export. So the following is a guide to working dump with no USE nor CREATE: `mysqldump -u root -p db_name --no-create-db > path/export.sql`